# XAMPP Access via 192.168.1.xxx - One OK, other not OK

Tags: xampp

I have 3 computers on my network - A, B and C.
Their internal addresses (now) are
A - 192.168.1.105
B - 192.168.1.113
C - 192.168.1.117
B and C are running identical websites. localhost works fine on B and C.
on A, 192.168.1.113/ works fine.
on A, 192.168.1.117/ does not work, it times out.
I assume something is wrong on my XAMPP setup on C. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please revise it (there is an `edit` link below it) and make the details more clear: are all three systems running http servers? What should `localhost` resolve to otherwise?

Comment: Obviously if you try to access one system from another one you need to take care that the post the http server listens on (typically 80) is reachable, so is open in the local firewall (package filter).

Comment: That's it! The windows 10 firewall settings were different. I made A's the same as B's and both now work. Thank you!